# How can i create environment in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

My project has an python version(3.10),i want to add python (3.6) version.
i dont want to delete the old version and my pc has not enough space for virtual machine.
How can i create env?
Can anyone help? Python was first installed directly, should I install anaconda?

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4iib.png)

I solved the problem by downloading the anaconda promt, creating a new env from there and running the vscode from within the anaconda, when I type the python version, the version I set appears when I type it in normcal cmd, the version 3.10 appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use different versions of python you can use tools such as [asfd](https://asdf-vm.com/) which will allow you to install as using different versions by switching in the terminal.

https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_6-set-a-version